# Why cudaMalloc() is not working?

Tags: c++, cuda

I am an absolute beginner when it comes to CUDA. I tried writing a simple vector summation program, following a sample program as base and it does not seem to work in the sense that cudaMalloc does not allocate memory.
I am using CUDA 5.0 and I work on ubuntu 13.04 
For compilation I simply type

`nvcc cuda1.cu -o cuda1`

The code snippet as is as follows

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<cuda.h>
#include<cuda_runtime_api.h>
#define N  5

__global__ void add(int *a, int *b, int *c)
{
        int tid = blockIdx.x;
        if (tid<N)
                c[tid] = a[tid] + b[tid];
}

int main(void)
{
        int a[N],b[N],c[N];
        int *dev_a, *dev_b, *dev_c;
        if (cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_a, N * sizeof(int))!= cudaSuccess)
                printf("Could not allocate memory");
 cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_b, N * sizeof(int));
        cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_c, N * sizeof(int));
        for (int i = 0; i<N; i++)
        {
                a[i] = i;
                b[i] = i;
        }
        cudaMemcpy(dev_a, a, N * sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
        cudaMemcpy(dev_b, b, N * sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
        add<<<N,1>>>(dev_a, dev_b, dev_c);
        cudaMemcpy(c, dev_c, N * sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
        for(int i =0; i<N; i++)
                printf("%d + %d = %d\n",a[i],b[i],c[i]);
        cudaFree(dev_a);
        cudaFree(dev_b);
        cudaFree(dev_c);
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: I assume you are getting the error message "Could not allocate memory".  It's likely a problem with your machine.  Please do [proper cuda error checking](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14038589) to decode the error for you and give you a message with more information about what is wrong.  Then post the *complete* output of your program, including all error messages.  You should also try running `nvidia-smi -a` on your machine, and report back the results from that.  Please edit this requested info into your question, don't try and paste into comments.  (I can run your program properly).

Answer (score 1):

Could you change your allocation logic to

```
cudaError_t rc = cudaMalloc((void **) &dev_a, N*sizeof(int));

if (rc != cudaSuccess)
    printf("Could not allocate memory: %d", rc);
```

Maybe the returncode gives some more insight.